# redhat 5.4 too slow on my hp Elitebook 8440p

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, hp-elitebook

I installed RedHat Enterprise 64bit 5.4 on my hp Elitebook 8440p however the performance is disturbing. When I am typing, the computer seems to hang and repeats some keys. I also note that coping documents takes longer than expected. For example, copying a 3GB file takes almost 1hr 40mins.

The installation is on a different partition, `fdisk -l` output :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 750.2 GB, 750156374016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 91201 cylinders, total 1465149168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000d9ccc

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sda1   *    61444096   125237248    31896576+  83  Linux 
/dev/sda2            2048    61444095    30721024   83  Linux 
/dev/sda3       125239296  1446719487   660740096    b  W95 FAT32
/dev/sda4      1446719488  1465147391     9213952    5  Extended
/dev/sda5      1446721536  1464125439     8701952   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6      1464127488  1465147391      509952   83  Linux


/dev/sda2 ===> where redhat installation.
/dev/sda6 ===> redhat swap partition.

Partition table entries are not in disk order
```

What could be wrong with the installation because i followed all the required instructions.

Comment: First of all, why would you want to install RH Enterprise on a laptop? Could you try a live Linux session (of a non-server edition Linux)? Do you have the same problems there?

Comment: @terdon i installed redhat on the laptop since that is the only resource i have to learn how to use redhat. also i have my friends who have installed redhat on their laptops and its working fine.

Comment: Your hardware might not be supported as well as your friends hardware is. RH is made for stability - old, but proven, software. Not a lot of support for a modern laptop.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to use rhel, you will be glad to use fedora (based on redhat and much more modern).

Comment: It's the other way around.  Fedora is the test bed for what is eventually incorporated into RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 5 is quite old and probably doesn't support the hardware in your machine well. You probably will need to run a more modern distro. RHEL 6 (or CentOS 6) should do.

Or just run a recent distro with Red Hat in a virtual machine.